# Checking if relationship exists using CloudCode Parse.com

Tags: javascript, database-design, parse-platform

How would I check to see if a given PFUser is friends with another user given a PFUser and an array of other PFUsers in the cloud?

Something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Message", function(request, response) {
  if (request.object.get("creator") != NULL) {

    var user = request.object.get("creator");
    var error = false;

    for (somepfuser in request.object.get("recipients")
           if (user and somepfuser are NOT in friends table)
                   error = true;             

  if (error)
   response.error("you must be friends to send message");
  else
    response.success();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a promise series where each promise check the relationship between the users pair in the friends table. Moreover, you should do it in a custom function instead of an event listener (like beforeSave or afterSave ... ) due the Parse restrictions on the time execution limit. For event listener like these you have 3 seconds maximum, in a custom function you'll have up to 7 seconds before parse drop the request.

see promise series reference: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-series

and promise series example: [wait for query to finish before sending response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296625/wait-for-query-to-finish-before-sending-response/22298310#22298310)

hope it helps